# Python install google-research/summae

Tags: python, pip

Trying to install google-research/summae to summarize a tonne of paragraphs that are way too long. Having trouble because python cannot import the modules as the code was downloaded from git, and not through pip... Therefore the build script cannot find these modules in the system path.

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'summae.process_rocstories.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'summae.process_rocstories' while trying to find 'summae.process_rocstories.py')
```

I tried manually to add these paths to the system path, ie.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../google-research/summae')
quit()
```

But it gives pretty much the same error.

Anyone know how to install this module as it is not available through pip to install, and the command,

```
+ python3 -m summae.process_rocstories.py --raw_dir=/home/...
```

Doesn't work (due to the module not being available in the sytem path)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the git package via pip using a similar command to this:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/openai/gym.git
```